# Cannot connect to belkin router through linux mint

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, realtek

I recently installed Linux Mint 13 alongside windows 7. I have a Realtek RTL8191SEvB Wireless Card. This work's fine with any router. However when I try to connect to a Belkin G Wireless Router it constantly says the passwords or encryption type are incorrect. They are not. I can connect to the Belkin router when I start my laptop (a toshiba satelite) with windows. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if there is any difference between cryptography algorithms used by the different routers (e.g. WEP, WPA-TKIP, WPA2-TKIP, WPA2-AES).

Comment: Its WPA 2. Every other computer in the house can connect to it using that setting...

Answer (score 1):

When you say you installed it alongside windows do you mean that you are dual booting windows and mint? Or are you running a virtual instance within windows?

Either way try this from the command line:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up && iwlist wlan0 scan | egrep -i "ssid|cipher"
```

If you get some kind of error check to see if you even have a wlan0 config file in your network-scripts folder. You can omit the pipe to egrep if you want a bunch of irrelevant info. Then do:

```
 iwconfig wlan0 essid "your network name goes here" key s:"your wireless password"
 dhclient wlan0
```

Comment: I tried the first command and I got:

Comment: I tried the first command and I got: ESSID: "my network name" Group Cipher : TKIP   Pairwise Cipher (1) : CCMP    Group Cipher : TKIP   Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP. I think iwconfig does not support WPA only WEP....